# How can I add a constraint to a Django model that forces two fields to match?

Tags: django, django-models, check-constraints

I need to add a constraint to my Company model that makes sure that if `state` is defined that `country` is also defined and that `state__country` matches `country`.

**My Models**

```
from django.db.models import F, Q

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)


class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country, on_delete=models.PROTECT, to_field="abbr", default="US"
    )


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(
        State,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="companies",
    )
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="companies",
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                # This causes an error:
                check=(Q(state__isnull=True) | Q(state__country=F("country"))),
                name="state_and_country_must_match",
            ),
        ]
```

When I run the migration, I get the following error caused by `Q(state__country=F("country"))`:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Joined field references are not permitted in this query
```

So, what's the correct way to write this?

By the way, another option would be to for `country` to be `None` if `state` is defined, but I'd rather not do that as I'd like to be able to get all companies in a country using `country.companies`.

Comment: Why store the `country` in the `company` anway? Why not derive the `country` from the `state`?

Comment: Because not all countries have states or state equivalents.

Comment: you can make a "proxy state". So imagine that country X has no state, you make a state with the name X as single state of country X. You can for example use a boolean field that specify if it is a proxy.

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting option. It would mean changing my models, which already have a lot of data, but it' would be pretty straightforward to do. I'd still like to know about the check constraint though.

Comment: in most databases, you can not do that. You can only implement such a thing, if the database supports this, with *triggers*. Normally a check can not look for data "outside" the table.

Comment: A flipped approach is to not allow countries on the company model that have states. With a bit of research and some data entry, you can either mark countries as "having states" or enter all states for all countries that have them and use `limit_choices_to` with a `states__isnull` filter. While countries are not immutable, they also do not change frequently...